# add selected multiple radio buttons value and uniqueId to an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: radio options]

I am mapping multiple radio buttons (group) options and when the user click on radio buttons, would like to add selected values and uniqueIds to an array.

with my current code I can get the value that I am currently clicking on but can't add to array.

```
{result !== null && result.length > 0 ? (
    <div>
      {result.map(item => {
        const label = item.question
        const listOptions = item.options.map(item => {
          return (
            <Radio
              name={item.uniqueId}
              inline
              value={item.uniqueId}
              key={item.uniqueId}
              className="radio-options"
              checked={item.checked}
              onChange={e => {

                this.handleChange(label, uniqueId);
              }}
            >
              {item.options}
            </Radio>
          );
        });

        return (
          <div className="radio-options-overview">
            <p>{label}</p>
            {listOptions}
          </div>
        );
      })}
```

```
handleChange = (label, uniqueId) => {
  console.log(label, uniqueId);
  let addToArray = [];
  this.setState({ selectedItems: addToArray})
};
```

array would look something like this,

```
[
  { "label": "ageRange", "uniquId": 2 },
  { "label": "smoker", "uniquId": 1 },
  { "label": "exOption", "uniquId": 3 }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there. @Clarity provided good solution.
if you wanting to replace exisiting value and replace it with new one

**Try This**

```
handleChange = (label, uniqueId) => {
    const { selectedItems } = this.state
    // Find items that already exists in array
    const findExistingItem = selectedItems.find((item) => {
      return item.uniqueId === uniqueId;
    })

    if(findExistingItem) {
      // Remove found Item 
      selectedItems.splice(findExistingItem);
      // set the state with new values/object
      this.setState(state => ({
        selectedItems: [...state.selectedItems, {
          label, uniqueId
        }]
      }))
    } else {
      // if new Item is being added
      this.setState(state => ({
        selectedItems: [...state.selectedItems, {
          label, uniqueId
        }]
      }))
    }
};
```

Comment: It does replace but removes the whole array and adds the replaced one

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
handleChange = (label, uniqueId) => {
  this.setState(state => ({ selectedItems: [...state.selectedItems, uniqueId]}));
};
```

By using array spread and functional form of `setState` you make sure that you don't directly mutate the state and add the items to the latest state.

In case you'd want to add an object with a `label: uniqueId` pair, you could do like so:

```
handleChange = (label, uniqueId) => {
  this.setState(state => ({
    selectedItems: [...state.selectedItems, {
      [label]: uniqueId
    }]
  }));
};
```

EDIT: If you want to overwrite the items with the same labels, the easiest would be to store them as an object and not an array, so the item with the same label would overwrite an existing one:

```
handleChange = (label, uniqueId) => {
    this.setState(state => {
      return { selectedItems: { ...state.selectedItems, [label]: uniqueId } };
    });
  };
```

Comment: Hi, solution above adds the data to array but if I choose different option from radio button it doesn’t remove the other one but just add another one to array. I only need one value from each options. TX

Comment: Hi, I am again only able to save single value with your recent solution but middle one works perfect. just need to get only one value from each radio option.Tx

Comment: label and uniqueId aren't pairs, value needed is like this  `[{ "label": "ageRange", "uniquId": 2 }]` and so on

Answer (score -1):

Honestly, I don't understand, what are you trying to do, but if you need to add object (or something else) inside an array, you could use `.push()` method. For example:

```
let addToArray = [];
let test = {"label": "ageRange", "uniquId": 2};
addToArray.push(test);
console.log(addToArray); //[{label: "ageRange", uniquId: 2}]
```

Comment: yea I did exactly that aswell but for some reason `handleChange` function updates array to recently clicked radio button.

Comment: it seems because you're not adding new element, but replacing with the last clicked button